VScode intellisense with typescript const objects
export type Entry = {
  pagename: string;
  path: string;
  datasource: string;
};

export type BunchOfEntrys = {
  [key: string]: Entry;
};

export const BunchOfEntrys: BunchOfEntrys = {
   NAME_1: {
    pagename: 'Name 1',
    path: 'path/name1',
    datasource: 'data_name_1',
  },
  NAME_2: {
    pagename: 'Name 2',
    path: 'path/name2',
    datasource: 'data_name_2',
  },
} as const;

If I type the BunchOfEntrys with BunchOfEntrys, the IntelliSense is lost. If I remove the type, it's back. How can I safely type my const Object and also get IntelliSense?
I want to be able to enter a new entry, e.g. "NAME_3", and then use it in the rest of my repo with IntelliSense.

Does the satisfies keyword suits your need? Remove the explicit typing (: BunchOfEntrys) but add as const satisfies BunchOfEntrys; at the end.

If you want to use the fields you declare in your variable throughout the rest of the code you are going to have to change the type BunchOfTypes. As it is declared now, TS will never "know" that your const has the properties NAME_1, NAME_2, etc. Might I suggest leveraging enums like this:
export type Entry = {
  pagename: string;
  path: string;
  datasource: string;
};

export enum EntryKeys {
  NAME_1 = 'NAME_1',
  NAME_2 = 'NAME_2',
}

export type BunchOfEntrys = {
  [key in EntryKeys]: Entry;
};

export const bunchOfEntrys: BunchOfEntrys = {
   [EntryKeys.NAME_1]: {
    pagename: 'Name 1',
    path: 'path/name1',
    datasource: 'data_name_1',
  },
  [EntryKeys.NAME_2]: {
    pagename: 'Name 2',
    path: 'path/name2',
    datasource: 'data_name_2',
  },
};

Like this you can use the enum to control the keys of the bunchOfTypes variable. And you can access any entry using the syntax bunchOfTypes[EntryKeys.NAME_1].
Note I renamed the variable to follow JS convention of naming variables using camelCase.
